# Encoding video frames with libavcodec

Tags: visual-c++, encode, libavcodec

I am a newbie in video coding and I have a simple task to do for my own project.

Basically, I have a certain number of raw RGB frames in the memory which are easily accessible by pointers. I want to encode them using libavcoded. Initializing is fine but I couldn't really understand how I should feed these frame information to the codec. Should I use avpicture_fill function? Could you please shed some light on me, preferably with some examples. I am using MSVC++ environment.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of examples under the `doc` directory:

- [examples/avcodec.c](https://git.libav.org/?p=libav.git;a=blob;f=doc/examples/avcodec.c) - encoding or decoding audio or video with libavcodec
- [examples/output.c](https://git.libav.org/?p=libav.git;a=blob;f=doc/examples/output.c) - taking your encoded audio/video and muxing it (putting it in a container format like AVI) with libavformat